# Access S3 Bucket using Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have an Amazon S3 Bucket that contains nothing but image files. Is there a way using javascript (using jQuery is fine) to pull all of the files in the bucket into a website?

If so, can someone provide an example or a link to the doc explaining this?

Note: I looked through the AWS SDK docs for Javascript but not finding the answer.

Comment: Have you tried using the Listbucket methid from the API  ?

Comment: @Kiloreux - Can you share a link? I am new to using S3 and trying to understand it as well as find what I am looking for in the docs.

Comment: There you go  let me know if you need something else.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPListBucket.html

Comment: Get files list require an authentication keys pair which is not safe doing on client. A common pattern is to get a file/files URL on server side with TTL say 2 hours and pass to JS on client side.